# You May Run, But

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Curse you, wrinkled beast and bug!
>   Non-electric stifling plug!
>   Gross and slimy, like a slug!
>   Low of rank and low degree.
>   Most at times your host shall be.
>   Robert Smith’s unknown to thee!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> The common cold?

Curse you, wrinkled beast and bug!

> rhinovirus ==> wrinkled beast = rhino, bug = virus

Non-electric stifling plug!

> stopped up nose

Gross and slimy, like a slug!

> runny nose

Low of rank and low degree.

> common (low rank) and low degree fever may be associated with a cold (cold is also defined by low temperature/degree)

Most at times your host shall be.

> I don't know my host, but perhaps he's cold all the time?

Robert Smith’s unknown to thee!

> Robert Smith is a member of The Cure.  No cure for the common cold.

Comment: The first line was clueing (rot13) euvabivehf, otherwise great. Congrats! Edit that in for the tick.

Comment: (Not necessary for the tick, I was thinking low degree -> low temperature -> cold.)